# Apache Storm: Is the topology replicated on atleast one worker on a Supervisor Node?

Tags: apache-storm

I have just started learning about Apache Storm. One thing that I cannot understand is whether the entire topology is replicated on atleast one worker process on a supervisor node. If it is the case, then a component in the topology which is very compute intensive (and possibly gives better(performance) executed on a single machine by itself), is a potential bottleneck? If not, I assume Nimbus in a way "distributes" parts of topology across the cluster. How does it know how to optimally "distribute" the topology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storm does not replicate a topology. If you deploy a topology, all executor threads are distributed evenly over all worker nodes (using a round-robin scheduling mechanism). the number of worker nodes a topology can use, can be configured via `Config.setNumWorkers(int);`.

If you have a compute intensive bolt and you want to ensure that it is deployed to an own worker, you would need to implement a custom scheduler. See her for more details: https://xumingming.sinaapp.com/885/twitter-storm-how-to-develop-a-pluggable-scheduler/